# deploy shinyapps on shinyapps.io with reticulate and python

Tags: python, r, shiny, shinyapps, reticulate

I'm trying to deploy a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app which has a [python](/questions/tagged/python) backend on https://www.shinyapps.io.
I'm using `reticulate` package to let [r](/questions/tagged/r) communicate with [python](/questions/tagged/python).
Locally everything is fine.

To deploy I'm following this: https://github.com/ranikay/shiny-reticulate-app
I wrote a couple of lines of code at the beginning of `global.R`

```
if (!Sys.info()[['user']] == 'myuser'){
  # When running on shinyapps.io, create a virtualenv 
  envs<-reticulate::virtualenv_list()
  if(!'venv_shiny_app' %in% envs)
  {
  reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'venv_shiny_app', 
                                 python = '/usr/bin/python3')
  reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app', 
                                 packages = c('numpy',
                                              'python-xbrl',
                                              'pandas',
                                              'loguru',
                                              'xmltodict',
                                              'xlsxwriter',
                                              'bs4'))
  }
}
```

aiming at creating virtual environments and installing packages.
When trying to deploy I get this issue:

> Paths should be to files within proj directory : Line 30.

Line 30 is :

```
 reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'venv_shiny_app', 
                                 python = '/usr/bin/python3')
```

I'm quite confused. Can anyone please help me in debugging this?

Comment: What does your `.Rprofile` say?

Comment: Solved with sys.which('python'). Anyway it was just a warning , turns out that it is something that will not block deploy

Comment: (note to others) `Sys.which('python')` needs a capital S